# Model derivative endpoint fails downloading big sdb files as chunks

Tags: forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to download a big 3.5gb sdb file on a svf file from BIM360 using Derivative API.
Being a big file I'm trying to download it by chunks as explained here [this link](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/download-large-derivatives-chunks)

Below is my implementation using **RestSharp**:

```
static async Task DownloadAsync(string AccessToken, string RemotePath, string folderPath, Tuple<long, long, string> chunck, int retry)
{
    string pathToSave = Path.Combine(folderPath, chunck.Item3 + ".part");
    IRestClient client = new RestClient("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/");

    RestRequest vRequest = new RestRequest(RemotePath, Method.GET);
    vRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
    vRequest.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    vRequest.AddHeader("Range", "bytes=" + chunck.Item1 + "-" + chunck.Item2);
    IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(vRequest);
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
    {
        Tools.LogWriter("Error");
    }

    else
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes(pathToSave, response.RawBytes);
    }
}
```

Same using **WebClient**:

```
static async Task DownloadAsync(string AccessToken, string RemotePath, string folderPath, Tuple<long, long, string> chunck, int retry)
        {
            string pathToSave = Path.Combine(folderPath, chunck.Item3 + ".part");
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/" + RemotePath);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
            request.AddRange(chunck.Item1, chunck.Item2);
            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var output = File.Create(pathToSave))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
            }
        }
```

Using **HttpClient** with a retry:

```
static async Task DownloadAsync(string AccessToken, string RemotePath, string folderPath, Tuple<long, long, string> chunck, int retry)
{
    try
    {
        string pathToSave = Path.Combine(folderPath, chunck.Item3 + ".part");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(chunck.Item1, chunck.Item2);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/" + RemotePath))
        using (var output = File.Create(pathToSave))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (retry !=0)
        {
            await DownloadAsync(AccessToken, RemotePath, folderPath, chunck, retry -1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Async Download");
        }
    }
}
```

Downloaded chunk files are 50mb size and later combined into a single sdb file.
The procedure works for smaller sdb files - 300 to 2000 mb - but for this particular file RestClient stop receiving after downloading the 95% of the parts.

A few notes:

- Failing chunks are not always the same pieces
- The procedure fails before the access token expires.
- The program runs complete randomly 10% of times.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> The program runs complete randomly 10% of times. Failing chunks are not always the same pieces

Your code looks okay so looks like it's unstable/slow networking that's getting in the way ...

Our endpoints would time out if your requests take too long to finish or get interrupted by connection problems ...

> The procedure fails before the access token expires.

Before each request fires you can check if the token has expired already, say you can split the token by dot and decode the second part of the base64 content to see when it'd expire:

```
//eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOndyaXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOmNyZWF0ZSIsImNvZGU6YWxsIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6InpsSHhHSEZyUzBscUpRN1hoZHNoMElxcUdPVmlsTExQIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiS09KNkxmNDZERUtuNENUc0JSMEgwNjFaOVYyeERDaTdzSmlVOVhkVnZNTm9aWFV6YkJHUUxvTjJCRTR5UzZ2QiIsImV4cCI6MTU4NjQ5OTU0Nn0.WmBsqYXd74Ka_C2cX4zHEqdj1Exc9HdW2J858bd4rB4

{\"scope\":[\"data:read\",\"data:write\",\"bucket:read\",\"data:create\",\"code:all\"],\"client_id\":\"zlHxGHFrS0lqJQ7Xhdsh0IqqGOVilLLP\",\"aud\":\"https://autodesk.com/aud/jwtexp60\",\"jti\":\"KOJ6Lf46DEKn4CTsBR0H061Z9V2xDCi7sJiU9XdVvMNoZXUzbBGQLoN2BE4yS6vB\",\"exp\":1586499546}
```

**Suggestions**

- Break into even smaller chunks say 30,40 MB per chunk
- Wait a few between requests if there's too many chunks fired in parallel you might hit rating limit, see more [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/rate-limiting/)
- Improve/change your networking environment to get more bandwidth
- Switch the target data center of our services to EMEA if you are in Europe, see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/where-data-stored-currently) for details
- Try migrate your code to cloud (as Faas or web apps etc on AWS which is where our services are hosted and you might get more juice) to improve networking performance

Comment: Tried everything and we got the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

We tried Bryan's solutions with the same results:

- Hosting in AWS fails too.
- Wait between requests changed to 1000ms. Parts failed randomly
- Chunks of 20 mb idem previous point

We decided to change the workflow to download the json file and rebuild the sdb from them.

Comment: Good going - i am working with engineering to offer more flexibility around this with our upcoming enhancements to address issues/difficulties querying data so going forward hopefully you’d be able query the APIs to rebuild data to specs per your own requirements